# How to combine common values of two column while averaging the corresponding values of other columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
> df<- as.data.frame(cbind(a=c(rep(3, 5), rep(5, 5)), b=c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 2), rep(4, 2), rep(5, 2)), c=(11:20)))

> df
   a b  c
1  3 1 11
2  3 1 12
3  3 2 13
4  3 2 14
5  3 3 15
6  5 3 16
7  5 4 17
8  5 4 18
9  5 5 19
10 5 5 20
```

I want to combine the common elements of column "a" and "b" like the count function in plyr package does:

```
> count(df, vars= c("a", "b"))
```

But I also want to keep my column "c" that will contain the mean values of all the combined rows. As shown below in column "m"

```
a b freq    m
1 3 1    2 11.5
2 3 2    2 13.5
3 3 3    1 15.0
4 5 3    1 16.0
5 5 4    2 17.5
6 5 5    2 19.5
```

Any suggestion who can I do that

Answer (score 2):

We can group by 'a', 'b', then `summarise` to create the number of rows as 'freq' and `mean` of 'c' as 'm'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(a, b) %>%
   summarise(freq = n(), m= mean(c))
#    a     b  freq     m
#  (dbl) (dbl) (int) (dbl)
#1     3     1     2  11.5
#2     3     2     2  13.5
#3     3     3     1  15.0
#4     5     3     1  16.0
#5     5     4     2  17.5
#6     5     5     2  19.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)

res <- df[,.(freq=.N, m=mean(c)),by=.(a,b)]
res

   a b freq    m
1: 3 1    2 11.5
2: 3 2    2 13.5
3: 3 3    1 15.0
4: 5 3    1 16.0
5: 5 4    2 17.5
6: 5 5    2 19.5
```